# Extract Red Color

Tags: image, matlab

I want to extract only red rose. The following code is okay, but it does not extract. So, please help!

```
Image = imread('red_rose.jpeg');
mask = Image(:,:,2)<Image(:,:,1) & Image(:,:,3)<Image(:,:,1); 
Red_Image = bsxfun(@times, Image, uint8(mask));
imshow(Red_Image);
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain exactly what the output should be. Do you want to crop the image using a square around the red part of the flower? Do you want to to also remove the stalk from the cropped image? Can you maybe process this image in paint/photoshop and upload the desired result so we know what you want to do?

Comment: I want to get only red rose image

Comment: It doesn't help that you try to explain using the same words of the question. In any case, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40056713/3372061 ([this](http://feelgrafix.com/772775-color-splash.html) is what the OP there wanted to do).