# Color only a segment of an image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors

I'm trying to color only a segment of an image in Matlab. For example, I load an RGB image, then I obtain a mask with Otsu's method (`graythresh`). I want to keep the color only in the pixels that have value of `1` after applying `im2bw` with `graythresh` as the threshold. For example:

```
image = imread('peppers.png');
thr = graythresh(image);
bw = im2bw(image, thr);
```

With this code I obtain the following binary image:

[image: Binary image]

My goal is to keep the color in the white pixels.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another suggestion on how to replace the pixels we don't care about. This works by creating linear indices for each of the slices where black pixels exist in the `bw` image. The summation with the result of `find` is done because `bw` is the size of just one "slice" of `image` and this is how we get the indices for the other 2 slices.

Starting MATLAB 2016b:

```
image(find(~bw)+[0 numel(bw)*[1 2]]) = NaN;
```

In older versions:

```
image(bsxfun(@plus,find(~bw),[0 numel(bw)*[1 2]])) = NaN;
```

Then `imshow(image)` gives:

[image]

Note that `NaN` gets converted to `0` for [integer classes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html).

---

Following the clarification that the other pixels should be kept in their gray version, see the below code:

```
% Load image:
img = imread('peppers.png');
% Create a grayscale version:
grayimg = rgb2gray(img);
% Segment image:
if ~verLessThan('matlab','9.0') && exist('imbinarize.m','file') == 2
  % R2016a onward:
  bw = imbinarize(grayimg);
  % Alternatively, work on just one of the color channels, e.g. red:
  % bw = imbinarize(img(:,:,1));
else
  % Before R2016a:
  thr = graythresh(grayimg);
  bw = im2bw(grayimg, thr);
end
output_img = repmat(grayimg,[1 1 3]);
colorpix = bsxfun(@plus,find(bw),[0 numel(bw)*[1 2]]);
output_img(colorpix) = img(colorpix);
figure; imshow(output_img);
```

The result when binarizing using only the red channel:

[image: Gray + color]

Answer (score 0):

Your question misses "and replace the rest with black". here are two ways:

**A compact solution:** use [`bsxfun`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
newImage = bsxfun(@times, Image, cast(bw, 'like', Image));
```

Although I am glad with the previous one, you can also take a look at this step-by-step approach:

```
% separate the RGB layers:
R = image(:,:,1);
G = image(:,:,2);
B = image(:,:,3);

% change the values to zero or your desired color wherever bw is false:
R(~bw) = 0;
G(~bw) = 0;
B(~bw) = 0;

% concatenate the results:
newImage = cat(3, R, G, B);
```

Which can give you different replacements for the black region:

[image]

#### UPDATE:

According to the comments, the `false` area of `bw` should be replaced with grayscale image of the same input. This is how to achieve it:

```
image = imread('peppers.png');
thr = graythresh(image);
bw = im2bw(image, thr);
gr = rgb2gray(image); % generate grayscale image from RGB
newImage(repmat(~bw, 1, 1, 3)) = repmat(gr(~bw), 1, 1, 3); % substitude values
% figure; imshow(newImage)
```

With this result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, my question wasn't clear: I want the non-colored areas to be in grayscale, not completely black. For example: http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/4/772775-color-splash.jpg